# Make consumers in the consumer group idempotent while using mirror maker

Tags: apache-kafka, disaster-recovery, apache-kafka-mirrormaker

I am trying to perform Kafka cluster migration from one cluster to another cluster using Mirror Maker 2.0. I am using Kafka 2.8.1 which has good support for consumer-group replication and offset sync.
I have encountered a scenario where I want to migration a topic along with its producers and consumers from source cluster to target cluster.

Example:
I have topic `A` which I want to migrate, it has 3 partitions

```
source -> topic = A
destination -> topic = source.A
```

topic `A` is replicated as `source.A` in target cluster

I have a consumer-group `topic-a-reader-group` created at source cluster with 3 consumers. It is replicated at destination cluster with same name, I have created 1 consumers in this group at destination cluster.

Now when I producer messages at source cluster to topic `A`, it is consumed by 3 consumers are source cluster and this message will also get replicated at target cluster which is consumer by the consumer present in the consumer-group running at target cluster. Basically the message is read both by source consumer and target consumer. Duplicate read for consumer ultimately.

I want only one consumer to get this message, not to duplicate at source and destination.  In my application, I can't just turn off the consumer at source and move it to target cluster(time critical application). So I want to keep both consumers at source and target running for sometime and turn off source consumer after some duration where both are running active.

Is there any idempotence property available for consumer-group which let only one consumer-group to read the message in mirror maker scenario without being duplicated at source and target cluster?

Please suggest if there are any other approach to move consumers from source to target cluster without downtime.

Comment: As I understand the question, this isn't possible. The consumer group offsets from the two clusters don't know anything about one another, or the origins of the topic, or if other consumer groups even exist within their own clusters. In other words, this scenario is no different than two distinct groups reading the same topic in one cluster.

Comment: Thanks @OneCricketeer for the comment. Do you see any other approach to move consumers from source to target cluster without downtime?

Comment: Not in my experience. Even if you change bootstrap server DNS entry on the network, the consumer will not see that immediately, as the OS caches the old IP address, so you'd need to bounce the consumer. And after you change clusters, the consumer groups are still different, so you could end up with duplicates, or missed records.